# What's the meaning of __pagesize, __subpagesize, __malloc_header_size in basic_string's _S_create function

Tags: c++, stl

1. _S_create function in stl's basic_string uses these three variables to calculate an actual allocated size. Does anyone know why?
2. The interface of _S_create is

   _Rep* _S_create(size_type __capacity, size_type __old_capacity, const _Alloc& __alloc)

Why it need the __old_capacity parameter?

PS. It is the gnu stl.

Comment: Which STL implementation are you talking about?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Probably none, I bet he's using the C++ standard library.

Comment: Rephrasing Mats question: *What implementation of the standard library are you using?* The point being that none of those are standardized names, so the interpretation is up to where you read the code.

Answer (score 2):

The actual code explains fairly well how it uses the `_PageSize` and `_malloc_header_size`, if you are just bothered to read the comments (and it's rather shameful NOT to read the comments, after all someone probably spent more time writing those comments than I did writing this answer):

```
  // The standard places no restriction on allocating more memory
  // than is strictly needed within this layer at the moment or as
  // requested by an explicit application call to reserve().

  // Many malloc implementations perform quite poorly when an
  // application attempts to allocate memory in a stepwise fashion
  // growing each allocation size by only 1 char.  Additionally,
  // it makes little sense to allocate less linear memory than the
  // natural blocking size of the malloc implementation.
  // Unfortunately, we would need a somewhat low-level calculation
  // with tuned parameters to get this perfect for any particular
  // malloc implementation.  Fortunately, generalizations about
  // common features seen among implementations seems to suffice.

  // __pagesize need not match the actual VM page size for good
  // results in practice, thus we pick a common value on the low
  // side.  __malloc_header_size is an estimate of the amount of
  // overhead per memory allocation (in practice seen N * sizeof
  // (void*) where N is 0, 2 or 4).  According to folklore,
  // picking this value on the high side is better than
  // low-balling it (especially when this algorithm is used with
  // malloc implementations that allocate memory blocks rounded up
  // to a size which is a power of 2).
```

And Sebastian got it right (although it's written in a slightly different way):

```
  // The below implements an exponential growth policy, necessary to
  // meet amortized linear time requirements of the library: see
  // http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-07/msg00085.html.
  // It's active for allocations requiring an amount of memory above
  // system pagesize. This is consistent with the requirements of the
  // standard: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-07/msg00130.html
  if (__capacity > __old_capacity && __capacity < 2 * __old_capacity)
__capacity = 2 * __old_capacity;
```

the `__pagesize` is used here, to round it up a bit...

```
  const size_type __adj_size = __size + __malloc_header_size;
  if (__adj_size > __pagesize && __capacity > __old_capacity)
{
  const size_type __extra = __pagesize - __adj_size % __pagesize;
  __capacity += __extra / sizeof(_CharT);
  // Never allocate a string bigger than _S_max_size.
  if (__capacity > _S_max_size)
    __capacity = _S_max_size;
  __size = (__capacity + 1) * sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(_Rep);
}
```

The implementation I have doesn't have a `_subpagesize`, but I expect that's a similar rounding thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at libstdc++ or asking anyone with definite information, one possible implementation is

```
size_type __actual_capacity = max(__capacity, 2 * __old_capacity);
// do other stuff to create a _Rep.
```

This ensures *geometric growth* while also guaranteeing at least as much memory as is definitely needed.